# How can I make Python "import.util.module_from_spec" work more like "import""?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I am continuing the code for Ned Batchelder's byterun, a Python interpreter written in Python for Python versions other than Python 3.4. See [x-python](https://pypi.org/project/x-python/).

One of the long-standing concerns of this kind of approach is separating the interpreter namespace in imports from the interpreted program namespace.

Aside: Not separating the namespaces can be advantageous if you want fast interpreter which doesn't interpret into the imported modules, but separating the modules is more correct, although slower, and necessary when interpreting bytecode from a different Python version.

So when the interpreter encounters an `IMPORT_NAME` opcode, I would like to use `importlib.util` to basically have a *copy* of the module that is distinct from any import that the interpreter encounters.

The problem I have right now is these import differently and this can be seen using `hasattr()`.

Here is an example:

```
import importlib

module_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("textwrap")
textwrap_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_spec)
submodule = "fill"
print(hasattr(textwrap_module, submodule)) # False

import textwrap
print(hasattr(textwrap, submodule)) # True
```

How do I get the same behavior using `importlib.util`?

(I should note however that for `sys`, both can find the "path" submodule as an attribute of `sys`.)

Comment: What is the expected result of your mentioned code?

Comment: @Sabil I am not sure what you exactly want. If you run the program, the output's  first line is False, and the second one is True. What we want to happen is the submodule "fill" to get listed as an attribute of the imported textwrap module  (and imported) when importlib.util is used just like it is done when import is used.

Comment: I just add an explanation for you. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the module ever executed? If not, the assignment or declaration within the module has not yet put the child objects into the `__dir__` of the module object. From the version of this function in the standard file loader, when you call `module_from_spec` all you get is the module, and the members that logically belong to all modules. It has no contents.

(The system may load modules on different paths or in different states of use with other Loader objects, which may complicate this task overall. For `sys.path`, for instance, the module you get seems to be populated already.  Bear in mind that there is a sub-object here for a reason.  There is not just one Python Loader.)

If it is not already loaded, to get the module object populated, you would call

```
module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

(If it exists.)

For example on Python 3.8:

```
import importlib
module_spec = importlib.util.find_spec('textwrap')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_spec)
module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
print(module.fill)
```

will output:

```
<function fill at 0x7fae70e6fd90>
```

In older versions of Python, `exec_module` is missing, and you need to call:

```
module_spec.loader.load_module(module.__name__)
```

On 3.6 and later, however, the code above works as expected.

The information was gleaned by looking at  `importlib._bootstrap.py::_exec`, and the things that it calls.

There is still a question here as to whether imports inside the loaded module will end up in the global namespace, or your own.  But that is another issue.

Comment: The use of this is a Python interpreter written in Python. So when  the "IMPORT_NAME"  opcode is written, the `importlib` routine is called and the returns the module. That module gets pushed onto a stack. At some later point (presumably) some other Python bytecode operation will pop that and perhaps later it will look at an attribute of that module.  I find that  if I save the "spec"  returned from `importlib.util.find_spec(name)`, then I can use that in `spec.loader.load_module(name)` or `spec.loader.exec_module(module)` modelling what boostrap does.

Comment: You replicate the same behavior as import by executing those two additional lines.  You can get them called automatically, by putting them in the right place and using the rest of the import mechanism and having a properly hooked-up loader.  If the rest of that mechanism is not available to you because of the context, you will just have to manage to call them yourself.

Comment: The problem or weirdness is that this feels a little bit like magic. In fact I copied these lines from `_exec(spec, module)` in Python 3.8's `_bootstrap_external.py`  avoiding references to `sys.module` which isn't relevant here. And that code works in a wonky way referring to say issue 19713. which does not give me a good feel.  My experience with Python imports is that there still is a bit of awkwardness in there and additional work may be needed to make the API easier to use and not feel awkward.

Comment: But if you look at the code for module_from_spec, it does not load the module.  It creates it and puts the mandatory stuff in it.  Clearly loading is a next step.  You are just not far enough on along in the process to see what you want to get.  You can figure out who to call to do it, or you can just *do it*.  If you want the module to have contents, it has to be executed.

Comment: At the same time, on the loader I get in my own environment at least, exec_module, which is what I would want to call next, is missing.  I am not sure what that is about.  I think it may be a version thing.  I am running 3.6, so it may not be hooked up the same way as the longer-view docs seem to imply.  But clearly, you can make the right stuff be present if you write your own loader...

Comment: Ok - so if you can organize all of this nicely in the answer now that I think you understand what is needed, and do that within the timeout period I'll accept the answer.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, so in a better version of Python, this is smoother.  And the answer is clear.

Comment: The particular problem I have in that particular program is that it runs on and emulates lots of different versions of Python. That said, it is okay to use a more robust solution from a later Python to emulate an operation of an older Python.

Comment: And I pointed out the workaround for earlier versions, indirectly.  Check whether exec_module is not yet defined for those classes and use load_module by name instead if you want to accommodate older versions of Loader.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `importlib`. For some reason, it didn't load all module attributes.

Let's go through the below cases:

**Case 01 - Code:**

```
import importlib


module_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("textwrap")
textwrap_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_spec)
submodule = "fill"
print(f'Attributes: {dir(textwrap_module)}')
print(f'Attribute Found: {hasattr(textwrap_module, submodule)}')
```

**Case 01 - Output:**

```
Attributes: ['__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
Attribute Found: False
```

As you can see, in the attributes list, there's no attribute named `fill`. That's why it returns `False`.

**Case 02 - Code:**

```
import textwrap


print(f'Attributes: {dir(textwrap)}')
print(f'Attribute Found: {hasattr(textwrap, submodule)}') # True
```

**Case 02 - Output:**

```
Attributes: ['TextWrapper', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_leading_whitespace_re', '_whitespace', '_whitespace_only_re', 'dedent', 'fill', 'indent', 're', 'shorten', 'wrap']
Attribute Found: True
```

In this case, you can see in the attributes list, there's an attribute named `fill`. That's why it returns `True`.

**Reason Behind This**

```
# Bootstrap help #####################################################

# Until bootstrapping is complete, DO NOT import any modules that attempt
# to import importlib._bootstrap (directly or indirectly). Since this
# partially initialised package would be present in sys.modules, those
# modules would get an uninitialised copy of the source version, instead
# of a fully initialised version (either the frozen one or the one
# initialised below if the frozen one is not available).
```

- Reference for Python 3.9: [`importlib/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/importlib/__init__.py)
- Reference for Python 3.8: [`importlib/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/importlib/__init__.py)
- Reference for Python 3.4:    [`importlib/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/importlib/__init__.py)

**Conclusion:**

By analyzing the above two cases, we can say that importing modules through `importlib` works differently from the builtin `import` statement because of the above mentioned reason.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration of what the behavior is. I realize I wasn't clear in that I want to reproduce the behavior of `import` because that is what I am trying model. I wasn't looking for a more detailed explanation of behavior I don't want as opposed to the behavior I want, although that may be useful in figuring out how to correct.  I have changed the question title to make this more clear. But if you read the text and my reply to your comment it should have more been clear that this was the intent.